# Need help scanning an input in C

Tags: c

How would I scanf an input of "2 & 3"?
Currently, I have it set up as

```
char expr[10]={};
printf("Enter the expression:");
scanf("%s", expr);
```

And at the moment it is just grabbing the 2.

Comment: Yes, because that's what `%s` does in `scanf`, see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html. Here it clearly says that `%s` **matches a sequence of non-white-space characters**, so it will stop reading after the empty space after the `2`. My advice is to **not use** `scanf` at all (unless your really know how this function behaves) and instead use `fgets` to get the whole line and then parse it in a separate step with `sscanf` or some other function.

Comment: in addition to what @Pablo said, scanf has as it stands, no check on the length of the string so if somebody enters a 11 char string you have undefined behavior causing your program to potentially crash.

Comment: Look into the `fgets` function.

Answer (score 1):

With scanf, the entry must be limited to the size of the buffer -1. In your case 9. To include white-space characters we use `%[^\n]`, that means all the characters except '\n', which therefore makes `%9[^\n]`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char expr[10];
    printf("Enter the expression: ");
    scanf("%9[^\n]", expr);
    puts(expr);

    return 0;
}
```

If you have other entries in a row, you should also purge the keyboard buffer to get out the characters entered in excess and the '\n' which has not been removed.

Answer (score 0):

As [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) described: The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.
If you want to read a line from console, you can search "c get line" in google, you will get more results.
for example: founction [getline()](https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=1112)